# Sequence by category and year in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sequence

I have a structure table something like this:

[image: dbstructure]

My expected results is like,  when the user add a new data (if new value from kode will start sequence from 1, if the kode value already there, the sequence will continue.

[image: expected]

My query itself already work to reset the sequence based on yearly record, but I want also to try the sequence will start if the data has a new value in kode field. 
Here is my query so far:

```
$q_nomer_terakhir = $this->db->query("SELECT (MAX(no_agenda)) AS last FROM t_surat_keluar WHERE YEAR(tgl_catat) = '".$this->session->userdata('admin_ta')."'")->row_array();
$last   = str_pad(intval($q_nomer_terakhir['last']+1), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

how to create a second query for resetting the sequence based on my need?

Thanks,

Comment: add kode value as well in where condition of first query

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya  Thanks for advice, I add the kode value but the result not sequence (always 1).
Query:
`$q_nomer_terakhir = $this->db->query("SELECT (MAX(no_agenda)) AS last FROM t_surat_keluar WHERE kode AND YEAR(tgl_catat) = '".$this->session->userdata('admin_ta')."'")->row_array();
   $last = str_pad(intval($q_nomer_terakhir['last']+1), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: add ORDER BY ID DESC in query will get last record not need to check MAX(no_agenda) then

Comment: Hi @VishnuBhadoriya I don't get it, I tried to put the order and remove the MAX statement. But it nothing happened. If you don't mind, can you please share the complete example?
Thanks